# userSchema.pre for save is not working. I want to hash password before saving it into mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using pre function on schema for 'save', to hash password before saving. But getting an error. schemaName.pre is not a function.

I tried to use validate instead of save but that's also not working.

```
const userSchema = {
name: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    validate(value) {
        if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
            throw new Error('Email is invalid')
        }
    }
},
age: {
    type: Number,
    validate(value) {
        if (value < 0) {
            throw new Error('Age must be positive number')
        }
    }
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 7,

    validate(value) {
        if (value.toLowerCase().includes('password')) {
            throw new Error('Canno contain the string "Password".')
    }
    }
    }
    }
    userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    const user = this
    console.log('just before saving')
    next()
    })
```

I want to hash password before saving it into database.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in hashing passwords. Eventually, the following resolves it.
Earlier I used,

`this.password = bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12); this.cpassword = bcrypt.hash(this.cpassword, 12);`

but then using separate const variables for hash worked for me,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

maybe its work for you. you can write a pre-save method like this.
its work for me. please try this.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

    userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
      console.log('just before saving')

      const rounds = 10; // What you want number for round paasword

      const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, rounds);
      this.password = hash;
      next()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating schema with mongoose ? In your code, all i see is plain js object.
Try Like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        validate(value) {
            if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                throw new Error('Email is invalid')
            }
        }
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        validate(value) {
            if (value < 0) {
                throw new Error('Age must be positive number')
            }
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 7,

        validate(value) {
            if (value.toLowerCase().includes('password')) {
                throw new Error('Canno contain the string "Password".')
            }
        }
    }
});

// reference from above answer
userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    console.log('just before saving');

    const rounds = 10;

    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, rounds);
    this.password = hash;
    next();
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongooose = require('mongoose');

const bcrypt =require('bcryptjs')   


const user = new mongooose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    email: {
         type: String,
        required:true
    },
  
    password: {
         type: String,
        required:true
    },
    cpassword: {
         type: String,
        required:true
    }
})





user.pre('save',async function(next){

    if(this.isModified('password')){
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password,12);
    this.cpassword =await bcrypt.hash(this.cpassword,12);
    }
    next();
})



const User = mongooose.model('USER', user);

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: Please write a comment along with the code to improve clarity

Answer (score 0):

I tried using bcrypt (A library to help you hash passwords)

Step 1 - Install bcrypt

```
npm i bcrypt
```

Step 2 - Importing the installed library

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
```

Step 3 - Code for password hashing:-

```
contactSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (this.isModified("password")) {
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);  //converting to hash password
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: I did this and it says contactSchema.pre() is not a function, any help please?